# jQuery UI datepicker range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Check out this datepicker here:
http://destinationtravel.com/sunriver/

Basically you can select the start date and end date right after each other.  I want to mimic this using the jQuery UI date picker.  I've seen [this](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/), but that has 2 separate datepickers that simple select a start and end date not combining it into one date picker showing the range and coloring in the dates in between.

Any ideas, suggestions or examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check this out.. http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: Yeah I checked that out, it was very close to what I wanted.  I haven't gotten around to continue working on this.